# winsock receive only one byte long telegrams

Tags: winsock, recv

I am sending data over ethernet with winsock from server. On client side I found out that the char array I am sendig is split to characters. So If I send 1000 characters then recv function is called 1000 times to get whole message. Could anybody explain me why is that please? It does not look very efficient to me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: This isn't normal behaviour.  Post your code.

Comment: I just use  bytesSent = send(m_socket, buffer, bufferPos, 0); and bytesRecv = recv(m_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

Comment: I solved the problem, sorry and thank you.. I had some bullshit on bufffer size